# Evolve a Multi Layer Perceptron using genetic algorithms

Tags: python, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I want to evolve a neural network using a genetic algorithm in order to approximate mathematical functions (linear, cubic, sine, tanh, etc). The requirement is that the NN should be evolved in terms of topology, weights and activation function of the neurons. The evaluation function is one that will calculate the error between the output of the NN and the function that should be approximated (mean squared error).

My main concern is that I want to be able to have absolute control over the representation/encoding/genome as I want to evolve layers of neurons, their weights and their activation functions at the same time, so I have to come up with a chromosome that incorporates all of these things.

What tools would you recommend? I'm checking DEAP for evolving the neural network and I was thinking of PyLearn 2 for implementing the actual best configuration the GA will result in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state-of-the-art for neural nets is Torch7 that is written in Lua. This is what Facebook AI and Google DeepMind use (as well as my lab). But I guess lua is not the best language to implement the sampling algorithms.

The alternative state-of-the-art framework is written in python it is called Theano, but I have a strong preference towards Torch. However, both of them might be too much for your task.

An easy alternative could also be to use Autograd, an automatic numpy differentiation library https://github.com/HIPS/autograd to easily train your neural net and have absolute control over it. There are several examples in their documentation.

Finally, genetic algorithms is another name for Monte Carlo, and there are many resources around implementing such things python (ex. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41004/organising-code-for-a-genetic-algorithm-in-python or github).

DEAP sounds a good and popular choice, and PyEvolve is outdated.

Edit: I forgot to mention Keras (http://keras.io/) which actually might be another good alternative and is Theano based.

Answer (score 0):

You might also look at [Blocks](https://github.com/mila-udem/blocks).  It's a library built on theano that manages the computation graph via annotations of variables.  It allows richer (ie, more complex, more recurrancy, more of those weird neural-stack-like structures you daydreamed) models than libraries like keras, pylearn2, and lasgne.  Although those libraries might be better if you only want to 'evolve' the variations of the classical MLP architecture.